# Is this phasing/modulation normal?

Tags: sound-design

I'm just getting into sound design so excuse the wrong usage of terms. Here's the sound I designed in Massive:

It sounds really nice except that I would like it to be more static and constant. Although I don't use any modulation, I hear that this sound is sort of phasing. BTW, can this be considered as phasing or is it just simple evolving/modulation?

I tested taking away effects and it's clear that the use of dimension expander and reverb result in this phasing/modulation—and technically, to the best of my knowledge, it should be this way.

My question is: is it possible to make it more static and less evolving without sacrificing the stereo width?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure where to start... & I don't know Massive at all... but, if you're going to take what is essentially a mono sound & try to throw it out to broad stereo, the way you achieve it is by modulating each side separately.

That's basically what both the reverb & the dimension expander [which sounds like a copy of the old Roland Dimension D effect - a very distinct wide but mono-compatible chorus sound] are actually doing.

If you're going to attempt to broaden a 'static' sound, then your best bet might be to push individual notes out into the stereo field - this would depend on whether Massive can do that.

Alternatively, generate two similar sounds, not based on the same sample, & pan those L & R instead. try tweaking the tuning of one against the other - try to avoid sounds that would beat, as that would put back some modulation you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. So you recommend ditching the reverb as well? If I turn off the dimension expander, and leave only reverb, the panning remains.

Comment: If you want it to be static, you need to remove all the modulation elements. If all those elements are what spread it into the stereo field, then you have to either sacrifice the stereo, or spread it in other ways, as explained above.